# $.post() method not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

My jQuery script is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','#blogFrm',function(event){
        event.preventDefault;
        var u_id = $('input[name="u_id"]').val(),
            title = $('input[name="Title"]').val();
            content = $('#textAr').val();
            date = $('input[name="date"]').val(),
            url = 'http://localhost/blog/ajax.php';

        var posting = $.post(url, {
            bg_p: 'ss',
            u_id: u_id,
            title: title,
            content: content,
            date: date
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

But when this script is running in response I am not getting anything . Only error I can see in the console is that the

```
POST http://localhost/blog/ajax.php
```

This line turning into red, also I dont find any other error report

The ajax.php has this code

```
<?php

if($_POST['bg_p']=='ss'){

    echo 1; 

}



?>
```

Can any one help me out what could be the problem.

Thanks

Comment: The request turning red means that there is an error there, in your `ajax.php` file. Can you update your question with the code of that file, and also the exact error message.

Comment: If you look at the "Network" or "Net" tab in your browser's development tools, you can get a complete idea of what happened with that response.

Comment: If it turns red most of the times that means 500 internal server error. Put on error reporting in your ajax.php

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in the "Net" tab I get response as my current html page. Like the page is called index.php so its showing all the content of index.php

Comment: @Vikram Wait, it shows the content? So the plain PHP Code?

Comment: @YUNOWORK it shows the content of the page from where the call is being made , I updated the question with my Ajax,php file

Comment: This `event.preventDefault` should be like `event.preventDefault()`.